# A more powerful method than Python's find? A regex issue?

Tags: python, regex, string, find

I'm looking for a list of strings *and their variations* within a very large string.

What I want to do is find even the *implicit* matches between two strings.

For example, if my start string is `foo-bar`, I want the matching to find `Foo-bAr` `foo Bar`, or *even* ***`foo(bar...`.*** Of course, `foo-bar` should also return a match.

---

**EDIT:** More specifically, I need the following matches.

1. The string itself, case insenstive.
2. The string with spaces separating any of the characters
3. The string with parentheses separating any of the characters.

---

***How do I write an expression to meet these conditions?***

I realize this might require some tricky regex. The thing is, I have a large list of strings I need to search for, and I feel regex is just the tool for making this as robust as I need.

Perhaps regex isn't the best solution?

Thanks for your help guys. I'm still learning to think in regex.

Comment: Could you give a full list of conditions that you want the searched string to meet for it to match? This would be a ridiculous regex... Have you considered a case-insensitive search using hamming distance? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance

Comment: @rogaos What an interesting property. I can list a few specific requirements now. I'll add them in.

Comment: This is contradictory. Your specific rules say that you want to match the string itself with spaces/parens _separating_ any of the characters, but your examples show matching the string with spaces/parens _replacing_ one of the characters (and specifically replacing the one non-letter character, which seems like it could be significant).

Comment: I see. I think what I was originally going for was separating *or* replacing, not like anyone wanted to know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> def findString(inputStr, targetStr):
...     if convertToStringSoup(targetStr).find(convertToStringSoup(inputStr)) != -1:
...             return True
...     return False
... 
>>> def convertToStringSoup(testStr):
...     testStr = testStr.lower()
...     testStr = testStr.replace(" ", "")
...     testStr = testStr.replace("(", "")
...     testStr = testStr.replace(")", "")
...     return testStr
... 
>>> 
>>> findString("hello", "hello")
True
>>> findString("hello", "hello1")
True
>>> findString("hello", "hell!o1")
False
>>> findString("hello", "hell( o)1")
True
```

should work according to your specification. Obviously, could be optimized. You're asking about regex, which I'm thinking hard about, and will hopefully edit this question soon with something good. If this isn't too slow, though, regexps can be miserable, and readable is often better!

I noticed that you're repeatedly looking in the same big haystack. Obviously, you only have to convert that to "string soup" once!

Edit: I've been thinking about regex, and any regex you do would either need to have many clauses or the text would have to be modified pre-regex like I did in this answer. I haven't benchmarked string.find() vs re.find(), but I imagine the former would be faster in this case.

Comment: +1 for how you split it into functions. I'll give it a bit before accepting any answers though.

Comment: If you accept one, abarnert's should be faster. Disclaimer - I haven't benchmarked. (Unless of course I have a miraculous epiphany)

Comment: Although this answer isn't quite right. I really want your third test case to return true, since a substring if your input string would be true.

Comment: @jdero you should add that to your specification then. I'll modify this.

Comment: A stupid afterthought I for some reason thought was implied :D

Comment: Isn't it implied though? I already said we were looking for a string in a larger string, so there's no reason the larger string isn't "ajkdlsadlkjsakldjskl_helloo_idsopfiopd" etc.

Comment: @jdero It is... I just whipped this together looking at your bullets though. No reason not to add it. I changed it.

Comment: I sincerely doubt the performance is going to make a difference, so I'd use whichever one you find more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that your rules are right, and your examples are wrong, mainly since you added the rules later, as a clarification, after a bunch of questions. So:

> EDIT: More specifically, I need the following matches.
>
> 1. The string itself, case insenstive.
> 2. The string with spaces separating any of the characters
> 3. The string with parentheses separating any of the characters.

The simplest way to do this is to just remove spaces and parens, then do a case-insensitive search on the result. You don't even need regex for that. For example:

```
haystack.replace(' ', '').replace('(', '').upper().find(needle.upper())
```

Comment: I like this. fyi - this example is missing the removal of the closing paren, but as an example way better than mine.

Comment: @rogaos Pretty sure it's obvious ;) but good to point out for passer-by's I suppose.

Comment: @rogaos: Actually, it's pretty much the same as yours, so I'm not sure how it could be a lot better…

Comment: @abarnert I like the one-lineliness. Upon rereading, maybe not much faster.

Comment: I'm going to put it into one line, use his functions setup.. and accept his answer because he had answered first. They're both great. Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
[fF][oO]{2}[- ()][bB][aA][rR]
```

Test:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile("[fF][oO]{2}[- ()][bB][aA][rR]")
>>> m = pattern.match("foo-bar")
>>> m.group(0)
'foo-bar'
```

Comment: In short, is there a better way to handle the string case insensitivity?

Comment: Yes, there is. Just use the `re.IGNORECASE` flag and capital letters in the pattern will match lowercase letters in the search text, so you don't need to overcomplicate things the way Mingyu did.

Comment: @abarnert to the rescue. Thanks, that helps a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Using a regex, a case-insensitive search matches upper/lower case invariants, '[]' matches any contained characters and '|' lets you do multiple compares at once. Putting it all together, you can try:

```
import re
pairs = ['foo-bar', 'jane-doe']
regex = '|'.join(r'%s[ -\)]%s' % tuple(p.split('-')) for p in pairs)
print regex
results = re.findall(regex, your_text_here, re.IGNORECASE)
```